# Laplace transform of $\int_0^t f(s,t) ds$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I know how to find the Laplace transform of an integral of the form $\Gamma(t) := \int_0^t f(s) ds$, this is simply applying a formula, but I was wondering if a formula for the more general $\Gamma(t) := \int_0^t f(s,t) ds$ exists as well.

The particular case I am interested in is $\int_0^t f(s-t) g(s) ds$ for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your complex argument is $s$ :

$$\mathcal{L}\bigg\{\int_0^t f(s-t) g(s) ds\bigg\}(ω) = \frac{\mathcal{L}\{f(0)g(t)\}(ω)}{ω}$$

Comment: I check if this gives me what I need in my calculations.

Comment: It's the Laplace transormation of $f(t)$ with complex argument $s$, which is the most standard example. If something else is needed, make sure to specially redefine everything, because it makes a difference.

Comment: Well, $f$ and $g$ are both functions on the real line, so $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$, I don't really know what you mean by $f(t)$ with complex argument $s$. (I have no background when it comes to Laplace transforms)